# TypeError: By.cssSelector is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium

I'm using [npm's Selenium Webdriver.](https://www.npmjs.com/package/selenium-webdriver)

I can't make the `By.cssSelector` work. Everything else does: `By.tagName`, `By.id`, etc.

Code:

```
var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver'),
    By = require('selenium-webdriver').By,
    until = require('selenium-webdriver').until

var driver = new webdriver.Builder()
    .forBrowser('firefox')
    .build()

driver.get('http://www.facebook.com/')
driver.findElement(By.name('email')).sendKeys('xxx@gmail.com')
driver.findElement(By.name('pass')).sendKeys('xxx')
driver.findElement(By.id('pass')).submit()

driver.findElement(By.name('xhpc_message')).sendKeys('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UfvZvd-kjyo')

driver.wait(function () {
  return driver.isElementPresent(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".uiScaledImageContainer")))
}, 10000)
```

I get this error:

> alex@alex-K43U:~/node/sapp$ node app.js
>   /home/alex/node/sapp/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/goog/async/nexttick.js:41
>   goog.global.setTimeout(function() { throw exception; }, 0);
>                                         ^
>
> TypeError: By.cssSelector is not a function

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 14):

According to [this page](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/javascript/module_selenium-webdriver_namespace_By.html) it should be .css(selector), rather than .cssSelector(selector).

Comment: http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/javascript/module/selenium-webdriver/index_exports_By.html